# apt blocked by lock

Tags: apt, permissions

I am new to Ubuntu. I am loving it but I have this problem that I have not been able to solve even after reading the answers here. So, what should I do?

[image: The problem in a screenshot.]

Comment: Specifically: http://askubuntu.com/a/878982/158442

Comment: Welcome to `AS`. It's hard to read the information you are providing us.  You should copy the output and paste it to your question.  This was everyone can read the content by the fonts and fontsize of their computer environment.  We could copy and paste from the output to research the problem.  If a solution occurs, the whole thread will be in the searching engines where others can benefit.

Comment: James, I'll keep that in mind from next time onwards.
Muru, I had tried all that and it had not worked.
I'm happy to say that after about 2 hours of working on this, a few bug report sendings, I have figured it out myself. 
As it turns out, the Python dependencies were broken which, I think, had taken control (i.e. locked) apt. 
What I did was ran: sudo apt-get install python2.7
It's all good now and I'm able to work without any problems. Ubuntu is fun!